# Defining exact projection in GDAL command

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, proj

I am using `gdalwarp` to convert a tiff from one projection to another.

I want to specify the `t_srs` as the same transformation/projection type I've been using in QGIS which reads as below

```
+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +inv +proj=helmert +x=446.448 +y=-125.157 +z=542.06 +rx=0.15 +ry=0.247 +rz=0.842 +s=-20.489 +convention=position_vector +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=airy +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy
```

How can I define this?

I tried `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs '+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +inv +proj=helmert +x=446.448 +y=-125.157 +z=542.06 +rx=0.15 +ry=0.247 +rz=0.842 +s=-20.489 +convention=position_vector +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=airy +step +proj=pop +v_3 +step +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy' C:/test/input.tif C:/test/output.tif`

But I get the error

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
'+proj=pipeline
```

Comment: The first fix is to use double quotes `"+proj=...` but with your string it yielded another error for me `ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_crs_get_coordinate_system: Object is not a SingleCRS`.

Comment: Maybe you should use `-ct` instead of -s_srs and -t_srs because the pipeline defines the whole stuff.

Comment: @user30184 I've tried that and now the reprojected tiff is way off in the middle of nowhere. I'm very confused

Comment: I am not sure but somehow I feel like your pipeline is for 3857->27700. Do you want to convert 27700->3857?

Comment: @user30184 I do yes :) I've even tried ```+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=airy +step +proj=helmert +x=446.448 +y=-125.157 +z=542.06 +rx=0.15 +ry=0.247 +rz=0.842 +s=-20.489 +convention=position_vector +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=pop +v_3+step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0+ellps=WGS84``` and it nds up on the coast of africa